# VBA - Lotus Notes - Output Email History

Tags: excel, vba, email, lotus-notes

I hope someone can put me on the right path, I have code that simply outputs emails received today into an excel spreadsheet by connecting to the database and then popping out the `NotesDocument.Document` items. Now what I cannot see within those items is reference to History as I'd like to be able to tell whether these output email have been replied to.

[image: Where is this part located within Notes and how would I access reference to it?]

If anyone knows what I could look into or read to help me retrieve this information it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whoever voted to close: I do not see "missing focus". Think this question is totally valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the (FollowUpMemoSubform) in the mail template, you will see that it contains this section.

[image]

The appearance of these lines is controlled by hide-when formulas that check for a NotesItem called $RespondedTo. The logic for the first line ("This message has been replied to") is

```
@IsNewDoc | !@IsAvailable(DeliveredDate) | !@IsAvailable(PostedDate) |
!@IsAvailable($RespondedTo) | !$RespondedTo="1"
```

The hide-when formulas for the other two lines are similar, but they are checking for "2" or "3".

The basic logic is: It's been replied to if $RespondedTo is 1 or 3. It's been forwarded if $RespondedTo is 2 or 3. The checks of DeliveredDate and PostedDate are there (I think) to exclude drafts. The check of @IsNewDoc is there for when you are composing a brand new message that has not yet been saved, but that's not an issue for you since those messages aren't in the NSF file so you'll never read them.

Comment: I get the premise of this in Lotus Formula Language but is there a way I could use this for VBA as I don't see this applying to any Lotus Script Class?

Comment: It's an item. You can use NotesDocument.HasItem("$RespondedTo") to see if it exists in a mail message. If it does exist, you can use NotesDocument.GetItemValue("$RespondedTo") to check whether the value is "1", "2", or "3".  Note that GetItemValue always returns a variant array, so it is the zero element of that array that will contain the "1", "2", or "3".

Comment: Or, as an alternative to this, you can just use NotesSession.Evaluate() to work with the same formulas that are used in the hide-when formulas.. You will have to pass in a formula, which you can copy from above, and also pass in the NotesDocument as the second argument. Since these formulas return true or false, you will get a 1 or 0 for the result. It will not be an array -- just a 1 or a 0. (I don't recall whether the result will be numeric 1/0 or string "1"/"0". You can test that part out for yourself.)

Comment: Evaluate also returns an array ;). And it contains numerical 1 / 0 in element zero

Comment: Okay now I understand, Evaluate looks super useful actually! Thank you for your explanations RichardSchwartz and Tode

Comment: @Tode doc says it returns a scalar, but I guess the documentation has been known to be wrong :-)